# How to stop/cancel FileStream in copying VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, filestream

What is the proper way to stop the whole operation of the `FileStream` when copying multiple files. When i call the `Stop Download()` function, it stops, but when i start the copy again it doesn't start like the way it was. What should i do?

code:

```
Private dStop As Boolean = False

Dim streamRead As FileStream
Dim streamWrite As FileStream

Public Function StopDownload()
    dStop = True
    streamWrite.Flush()
    streamWrite.Close()
    streamRead.Close()
End Function

Public Sub Copier(ByVal URL As String, ByVal Location As String) As Boolean

    streamRead = New FileStream(URL, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
    streamWrite = New FileStream(Location, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
    Dim lngLen As Long = streamRead.Length - 1
    Dim byteBuffer(1048576) As Byte
    Dim intBytesRead As Integer

     While streamRead.Position < lngLen And dStop = False 'This is where i stop the process of copying
         intBytesRead = (streamRead.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 1048576))
         streamWrite.Write(byteBuffer, 0, intBytesRead)
         Pbar1.value = CInt(streamRead.Position / lngLen * 100)
         Application.DoEvents()    'do it
     End While 

     streamWrite.Flush()
     streamWrite.Close()
     streamRead.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have to put this at the beginning my `Copier` Public Sub.

```
dstop = False
```

for it to start a new copying process.

Comment: Is this a solution or just a continuation of your question? Because you should edit the question of you are to include more info.

Comment: Uhm i think this is a solution, because this solved my problem.

Comment: If it solved your problem it is a solution. I was just asking because I wasn't sure wether this actually was one, or just you including additional info for your question.